# Logging separately by module

Tags: python, logging, module

I have a python module that creates a logger; I call this in my **main** and log all messages in the main. How do I access this logger in a different module?

My code:

```
my_logger.py
import logging
import logging.handlers

def setup_logging(file_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(file_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    runlog_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s line-%(lineno)d\t\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')        
    runlog_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(file_name, when='midnight', backupCount=30)
    runlog_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    runlog_handler.setFormatter(runlog_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(runlog_handler)
    return logger

TestCode.py:

import my_logger
import someother_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = base_logger.setup_logging('testStatus.log')
    logger.info('--- SCRIPT RUNNING ---\n')
    param1 = 'parameter1'
    param2 = 'parameter2'
    logger.info(someother_module.get_status(param1, param2))
    logger.info('--- SCRIPT EXITING ---\n')
```

someother_module.py

```
def get_status(param1, param2):
    print('Parameter1: %s' % param1) # here, I would like to use the logger created in main
    print('Parameter2: %s' % param2)
```

Can I pass the logger from **main** to the somether_module's get_status?

Comment: did you try `logging.getLogger(file_name)` with the same name?

Comment: @Kache: That worked. Thank you. Please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll often find the [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) recommend using:

```py
# at module top-level
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Because you'll get loggers that communicate exactly where they're logging from (`foo_module.__name__` produces the full module path).

By the same mechanism, even if you've given it some different name, e.g. in your case `logging.getLogger('testStatus.log')`, you can always fetch that same logger by passing in that same name, even if in a different module.